# I cannot see content of my computer in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, storage

[image]

Memory is still occupied completely. `/dev/sda2` has 648GB used but still not visible to me. I have not deleted anything.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).